# VHDL Unknown identifier "signed" in numeric_std

Tags: vhdl

These are my declarations. Why it doesn't identify signed as a type? I have imported the numeric_std library, and in the documentation I see that it supports signed and unsigned. What is wrong here?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

use work.my_package.all;

entity landmark_1 is
  generic
        (data_length :integer := 8;
        address_length:integer:=3 );
        port ( clk:in std_logic;
        vin:in std_logic;
        rst:in std_logic;
        flag: in std_logic;
        din: in signed(data_length -1 downto 0)

        done: out std_logic
        );
end landmark_1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to include `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`